# Latex beamer: How to horizontally/vertically center text, ignoring other content

Tags: beamer

I would like to put some content, for example a beamercolorbox exactly in the middle of the page (horizontally/vertically centered) and then some other content on the bottom of a frame. Centering just the colorbox is easy:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \vfill
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[center]{title}
     example text
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
\end{frame}
```

How can I now insert some more content at the bottom without disturbing the vertical alignment?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

May be it's a little bit overkill but it works. Compile twice to watch the result.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node[anchor=center] at (current page.center) {
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center]{title}
     example text
  \end{beamercolorbox}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! Maybe you should add for those who are going to read this in the future, that outside of the tikzpicture environment you can add to the frame whatever you want without affecting the alignment.

Comment: @r_faszanatas What's the reason for a `beamercolorbox`? If you just want to put some text somewhere, a `TiKZ node` without the inner `beamercolorbox` is enough. And if you want to add some background to your slides, there exist better solutions.

Comment: There's no particular reason for the colorbox, thanks for pointing this out. I have modified my question accordingly. The problem occured when designing a custom title page for a beamer presentation, I would like to have the title etc. centered in the middle of the page and then add some additional content to the bottom left. I'm adding background via beamer's background template.

Answer (score 31):

I simply add a frame like this for my last slide. the [c] part centers the text vertically, while the \centering command is in charge of the horizontal centering. The template used in all your slides will be preserved.

```
\begin{frame}[c]{ }
\centering
Thank you!
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. How does this address the problem of having some more text at the very bottom?

Comment: Note that you need to end the paragraph with an empty line or `\par` in order to notify that the line is finished, otherwise `\centering` will not work.