# Vertically centering in Latex Beamer slightly too much up

Tags: beamer, spacing

One MWE of many (w and w/o the plain frame option, w and w/o the vfill, w and w/o the c frame option etc.):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]{}
\vfill
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\vfill
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces a horizontal line that is not exactly centered (using text instead does not work either). The ratio of the space above and below the line is approximately 4.5/5.5 in this case. Why?

PS: centering via TikZ as in [question 208633](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208633) works fine.

Comment: Is `\begin{frame}[c]{}
 \vskip0pt plus 1filll
 \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
 \vskip0pt plus 1filll
\end{frame}` centred for you?

Comment: That improves the situation but moves the line a bit too much down, i.e. barely below the center.

Comment: One issue may be that `\rule` is on the baseline. Editing LaRiFaRi's solution to `\rule[.5ex]{\linewidth}{1pt}` looks slightly more centred. Even better is `\begin{frame}[c]{}\null\vfill\null\rule[.5ex]{\textwidth}{1pt}\vfill\end{frame}`, though I'm not sure as why it works.

Comment: Does the comment of @campa solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, the second one with the nulls seems to be perfectly centered. If someone could write a real answer (including an explanation why the nulls change the behavior) I'd be happy to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @campa Can you please convert you comment into an answer?

Comment: @campa ping....

Comment: @samcarter Now I remember why I had written only a comment instead of an answer: It strongly depends on where I put the `\null`s, and I have no idea why exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addition to the [answer of campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354503/36296):

The same result as campa's third frame can also be achieved by a symmetrical definition of the `frametopskip` and `framebottomskip`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354503/36296
\begin{frame}[c]{} % this works
\null\vfill\null
ace\rule[.5ex]{.5\textwidth}{.5pt}
\vfill
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
% \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1.5fill\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
}
\makeatother
\begin{frame}[c]
aba\rule[.5ex]{.5\textwidth}{.5pt}abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is only a half-cocked answer, as I do not know exactly the behaviour behind it. One (minor) issue is that `\rule` gives a line on the baseline, though this is not the real problem. Consider the following example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{} % the problem
\vfill
ace\rule[.5ex]{.5\textwidth}{.5pt}
\vfill
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c]{} % slightly better
\null\vfill
ace\rule[.5ex]{.5\textwidth}{.5pt}
\vfill
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[c]{} % this works
\null\vfill\null
ace\rule[.5ex]{.5\textwidth}{.5pt}
\vfill
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The first frame is the not centered one. From experience I knew that just calling `\vfill` somewhere may be give unexpected results (TeX modes) so I put en empty box at the beginning of the frame. This gives the second frame in the example above, which is slightly better but not yet really centered. To get what we want I had to put *another* empty box *after* the `\vfill`. And I must admit I'm quite befuddled as to why...

[image]

Comment: Sorry it took so long... and thanks for adding the pictures. Do you by any means have any idea about what is going on? I'm going through the `beamer` code in the hope to find how the centred frames are handled.

Comment: I guess the "problem" is that the `frametopskip` for centred frames is more stretchy? But that's just a guess, I did not look in the code.

Comment: For a centred frame: `\beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%` and `\beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1.5fill\relax%`. Now if ones adjusts the `bottomskip` to, say, `0pt plus 1.1fill`, the rule looks to be centred.

Comment: And with a symmetrical definition of `1fill` in both, I get the same results as your third frame.