# Vertically centering a tikz graph in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am wondering how to make a graph vertically centered in a slide. The graph is drawn using tikz. The code is below. Thank you very much!

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{AnnArbor}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{wolverine} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{plum(traditional)}{rgb}{0.56, 0.27, 0.52}
\definecolor{darkpastelgreen}{rgb}{0.01, 0.75, 0.24}
\definecolor{hotpink}{rgb}{1.0, 0.41, 0.71}
\definecolor{lavenderindigo}{rgb}{0.58, 0.34, 0.92}
\definecolor{mygray1}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{mygray2}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{mygray3}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{mygray4}{gray}{0.2}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Distraction_slides_reference.bib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,intersections,through,backgrounds} 
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{upgreek}


\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};}%

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem*{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem*{definition*}{Definition}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{proposition*}{Proposition}
\newtheorem*{assumption*}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\providecommand{\ux}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\ux}[1]{\underline{#1}}


\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\setbeamercovered{transparent}  

\title{A}
\author{B}
\institute{C}
\date{09/03/2021}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.6,yscale=0.6]

\draw [fill] (-11.5,6) circle [radius=0.7];
\draw [fill=gray] (-10,6) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill=gray] (-8.8,6) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill=gray] (-7.6,6) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill=gray] (-6.4,6) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill] (-3.5,6) circle [radius=0.7];
\draw [fill=gray] (0,2.4) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill=gray] (2,2.4) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill=gray] (4,2.4) circle [radius=0.45];  
\draw [fill=gray] (6,2.4) circle [radius=0.45];

\draw (0,7.8) -- (-3,6.2);
\draw (0,7.8) -- (3,6.2);
\draw (3,6.2) -- (1,4);
\draw (3,6.2) -- (5,4);
\draw (1,4) -- (0,2.8);
\draw (1,4) -- (2,2.8);
\draw (5,4) -- (4,2.8);
\draw (5,4) -- (6,2.8);

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Here is the output for the codes of Holger Karl on 2021/9/2:
[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263268

Answer (score 0):

Would `\vfill` before and after the figure environment work? Something like this, with the code trimmed down:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{AnnArbor}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{wolverine} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

% possibly add vfill here: 
%\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.4,yscale=0.4]

\draw [fill] (-11.5,6) circle [radius=0.7];
\draw [fill=gray] (-10,6) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill=gray] (-8.8,6) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill=gray] (-7.6,6) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill=gray] (-6.4,6) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill] (-3.5,6) circle [radius=0.7];
\draw [fill=gray] (0,2.4) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill=gray] (2,2.4) circle [radius=0.45];
\draw [fill=gray] (4,2.4) circle [radius=0.45];  
\draw [fill=gray] (6,2.4) circle [radius=0.45];

\draw (0,7.8) -- (-3,6.2);
\draw (0,7.8) -- (3,6.2);
\draw (3,6.2) -- (1,4);
\draw (3,6.2) -- (5,4);
\draw (1,4) -- (0,2.8);
\draw (1,4) -- (2,2.8);
\draw (5,4) -- (4,2.8);
\draw (5,4) -- (6,2.8);

\end{tikzpicture}    

% possibly add vfill here: 
%\vfill

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: Hi, I tried this one, but it is still not vertically centered. You can find the output in my edited question.

Comment: Looks fine to me. What do you expect to achieve? Maybe we mean different things?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Ignasi in this [Latex beamer: How to horizontally/vertically center text, ignoring other content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208633/latex-beamer-how-to-horizontally-vertically-center-text-ignoring-other-content)

For my case, it is

```
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node[anchor=center] at (current page.center) {
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.6,yscale=0.6]
blabla
\end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I tried "indent with four spaces" to make a block of my code but I failed.

Comment: Perhaps it's easier if you enclose your code between three consecutive french accents for open and other three for close (see my edit)

Comment: BTW, it's probably not a good idea to nest two `tikzpicture`s.

Comment: I fail to see the problem? after removing a lot of clutter from the preamble, the figure looks perfectly vertically centred already? And yes, nesting tikzpictures is asking for trouble...

Comment: @HolgerKarl Could you please post the code (after removing the clutter)? Maybe some of them cause the problem.

Comment: sure... edited my previous answer