# Vertically centering text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, article

I have a block of text that I want to be in the center of the page, i.e. there is the same amount of space between the top of the paper and the start of the bock and between the bottom of the paper and the end of the block.
**The block has to be centered regardless of other blocks on the page**

To be more specific, I want to write a letter that consists of two paragraphs, centered vertically on the page. There also has to be an address on the top, but I do not want this to influence the centering.

I want to achieve the effect from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208633/latex-beamer-how-to-horizontally-vertically-center-text-ignoring-other-content), but not for Beamer.

Comment: solution in given link works at any `\documentclass{...}` ...

Comment: You on one hand say at the center of the "page" which many will take to mean the printable area of the paper (excluding margins), while you also indicate centering with respect to the "paper".  Since the printable page may not be centered on the paper, the distinction is quite important what you seek.

Answer (score 2):

Centered with respect to the **PAPER**, regardless of other content on page, stealing my answer from [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831)

**REVISED ANSWER**

This accounts for the OP's edited purpose, namely "I want to write a letter that consists of two paragraphs, centered vertically on the page. There also has to be an address on the top, but I do not want this to influence the centering."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\begin{document}
\noindent Name\\
Address\\
Anytown, USA 12345

\atxy{.5\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\parbox{\textwidth}{\parindent1em\relax\lipsum[1-2]}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\begin{document}
\atxy{.5\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}{%
  \fboxsep=200pt\relax\makebox[0pt]{\fbox{\Huge I AM CENTERED}}}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}% or book, report, etc
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % some text
\clearpage % go to next page.
\mbox{}
\vfill
\lipsum[2] % more text, vertically centered
\vfill
\mbox{}
\clearpage % go to next page
\lipsum[3] % yet more text
\end{document}
```

Or if you want the middle text centered with respect to the before and after texts then delete the two `\clearpage` and `\mbox{}` macros.

Comment: Thank you! However, can I have the three pages "merged"? The point is that I need to put an address into the top corner, but I do not want it to influence the centering of the 2nd text.

Comment: @cubeception Your original question was just about centering text on a page with no mention that there might be other text before and after. I have extended my answer.

Comment: @cubeception My apologies, I did not read your question carefully enough. You did mention other text on the page.