# How to vertically center text in beamer notes

Tags: beamer, positioning, presentations, pgfpages

I have some `beamer` slides with notes on the right hand side, and would like to horizontally and vertically center the text on the note page.

I've tried:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=7mm,text margin right=7mm}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title}
    Some text in the main slides
\end{frame}

\note{
    \begin{center}
        Center this horizontally and vertically
    \end{center}
}
%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

I know we can use `\begin{frame}[c]` in the main slides but such option is not available for notes pages. Besides [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208635/2720), is there a simple/straightforward approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `\vfill`s.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=7mm,text margin right=7mm}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide Title}
    Some text in the main slides
\end{frame}

\note{\vfill
    \begin{center}
        Center this horizontally and vertically
    \end{center}
\vfill  
}
%------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]